# Overloading methods for different geomethrical figures areas

Tags: c#

I need to overload a method for it to be able to calculate the area of a circle, square, rectangle, triangle and a trapezoid. I think I've got them all figured out but the circle seems to be a problem.

```
    static void Pole(int x, double y = 3.14)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x * x * y);
    }
    static int Pole(int x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }
    static int Pole(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
    static int Pole(int x, int y, int z = 2)
    {
        return x * y / z;
    }
    static int Pole(int x, int y, int v, int z = 2)
    {
        return (x + y) / z * v;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 2;
        int y = 3.14;
        Console.WriteLine(Pole(x, y));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: And.. what *is* the problem?

Comment: Overloading is **not** for modifying behavior. That's what overriding is for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what problem you're getting, but I can probably guess it's one of the following:

1) You're getting an error because one of your overload methods is returning void while the others are returning int (they all have to be the same)
or
2) What your Main method is calling is this method `static int Pole(int x, int y)` and not `static void Pole(int x, double y = 3.14)`, which I'm assuming is the "Circle"; because you're passing in two ints instead of one int and one double.

Have you tried changing int to double for y in your Main method?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 2;
    double y = 3.14;
    Console.WriteLine(Pole(x, y));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

also why dont you just pass in one parameter and have it multiply by 3.14 for the Pole overload method that's tasked with calculating the circle?

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to calculate a circle
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x"></param>      
/// <returns></returns>
static double Pole(int x)
{
     return 3.14(x * x);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(Pole(x));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Another tip: add some notes in  your code. You have 5 methods named Pole, one accepting one more int parameter than the last one and each of the 5 methods are calculating for a different shape.

Adding a summary to each method or just a simple comment will help you and anyone else trying to read your code, moving forward.

*Important:* Because these are overloads, you're going to need to change all your methods to return double instead of int just for the sake of the "Circle" Pole method. Having it as the only void method was probably causing the error for you to begin with.

This should be enough to get you started:

```
//Circle
static double Pole(int x, double y)
{
    if(y != 3.14)
        y = 3.14;

    return y(x * x);
}

//Square
static double Pole(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}

//Rectangle
static double Pole(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

//Triangle
static double Pole(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if(z != 2)
        z = 2;

    return x * y / z;
}

//Trapezoid
static double Pole(int x, int y, int v, int z)
{
    if(z != 2)
        z = 2;

    return (x + y) / z * v;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 2;
    double y = 3.14;
    Console.WriteLine(Pole(x, y));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```